# How to square the value and sum together in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, square-root

In Javascript, I have a scenario to implement the following:

Let's take a list of integer below, take each integer in that list and double the value, then square the doubled value, then as output, sum together all the squared values. E.g.:

```
doubleandSquareandSum[1] // 4 
doubleandSquareandSum[1, 2] // 20 
doubleandSquareandSum[1, 2, 3] // 56 
doubleandSquareandSum[1, 2, 3, 4] // 120
```

JS Code tried:

```
function doubleandSquareandSum(arr) {

    ret= [];

    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        ret.push(arr[i] * arr[i]);
    }

    return ret;     
}
```

I know `Math.sqrt`, but not sure how to implement it here.
I have tried something above, but didn't worked. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would `reduce`, adding the square of each doubled item to the accumulator:

```js
const doubleandSquareandSum = arr => arr.reduce((a, num) => a + ((2 * num) ** 2), 0);

console.log(doubleandSquareandSum([1])) // 4
console.log(doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2])) // 20
console.log(doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2, 3])) // 56
console.log(doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2, 3, 4])) // 120
```

Comment: Great :) So simple and crispy

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing the value in array again, just calculate the new value and add it to sum variable.

```js
doubleandSquareandSum([1]) // 4 
doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2]) // 20 
doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2, 3]) // 56 
doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2, 3, 4]) // 120

function doubleandSquareandSum(arr) {

  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    sum += 4 * arr[i] * arr[i];
  }
  console.log(sum);
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a functional approach by taking single small functions to build intermediate results and the final result.

```js
const
    twice = v => 2 * v,
    square = v => v * v,
    pipe = fn => v => fn.reduce((x, f) => f(x), v),
    twiceAndSquare = pipe([twice, square]),
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    doubleandSquareandSum = array => array.map(twiceAndSquare).reduce(add);

console.log(doubleandSquareandSum([1]));          //   4 
console.log(doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2]));       //  20 
console.log(doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2, 3]));    //  56 
console.log(doubleandSquareandSum([1, 2, 3, 4])); // 120
```